# Browser not showing the change after updating User.vue file

Tags: laravel

My question is when I change anything in the Example.vue, User.vue or any of my Vue components and refresh my browser it doesn't get the updates at all, the old values still remain. Even if I delete the entire code in any of my components it's still there. I clear my browser cache, restart the computer, run dev, npm run watch, ran dump-autoload, Php artisan clear cache. I am using laravel 5.8. I am running or of ideas. Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Did you disable browser cache? If using google chrome -> open dev tools -> network tab -> check 'disable cache'. Did you specify 'dev' as environment in your .env file?

Comment: Yes I already did that. Still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you have supervisor running on your pc? If you do, run

```
supervisorctl restart all
```

[read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration) 
[and here](http://supervisord.org/index.html)